# how to save checkbox values in database in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, checkbox

How to save checkbox values in database in magento ?
My code is:

```
$fieldset->addField('expertise', 'checkboxes', array(
    'name'      => 'expertise',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Expertise Area'),
    'required'  => true,
    'values'   =>array('Php','.Net')
));
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it working well you need to:

1) In your **Form** class, before `$form->setValues($data);` add the following:

```
if (!is_array($data['expertise'])) {
    $data['expertise'] = explode(',', $data['expertise']);
}
```

2) In your **Controller** class, before `$model->setData($data);` add the following:

```
if (is_array($data['expertise'])) {
    $data['expertise'] = implode(',', $data['expertise']);
}
```

Moreover, input component of "checkbox" type is not standard in Magento and it works incorrectly in some cases. The best solution here is to use "multiselect" component:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'expertise', 'multiselect', array(
    'name'     => 'expertise',
    'label'    => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Expertise Area'),
    'required' => true,
    'values'   => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Php',
            'value' => 'php'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => '.Net',
            'value' => 'dotnet'
        ),
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following things.

For example:

if your attribute is `expertise` Then in your controller saveAction() when saving the checkbox data do

```
$expertise = isset($your_form_Data['expertise']) ? 1 : 0;
```

**For Grid and Form Page**

In your controller you should have Mage::register(...)->getData() or Mage::register(...)

```
public function editAction()
     ....
     Mage::register('example_data', $model);
```

On your form _prepareForm()

```
$model = Mage::registry('example_data'); // NOTE registry('example_data'); NOT registry('example_data')->getData();

$fieldset->addField('entire_range', 'checkbox', array(
      ....
      'checked'    => $model->getExpertise()==1 ? 'true' : 'false',
       ......
))
```

On your grid _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('expertise', array(
    ....
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'index'    => 'expertise',
    'values'   => array(1,2),
    'field_name' => 'checkbox_name',
    ....
));
```